# VS2005 Setup and Deployment - MSI Installer on reboot

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-installer, setup-deployment

I built a VS 2005 Setup and Deployment project and i'm able to install the setup without any problems.  But, if I reboot my computer, the setup utility is being run again, asking me to install the software again (It already exists).  I have not run into this problem before, any help would be greatly apperciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- Check the [Event Log](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308427), it will show what missing component/file/whatever is causing the installer to run.
- Try enabling [Windows Installer Logging](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/223300) and looking at the log files to see what might be failing.
- [Validate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369206(VS.85).aspx) your resulting MSI using [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557.aspx), it's available as part of the [Windows Installer 4.5 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557.aspx) (look for **orca.msi** in the **TOOLS** folder)